# 2 1/2 year old still crying after a year at daycare drop off

Tags: crying, daycare

My 2.5 year old is still crying every day I drop him off at daycare. They tell me he stops after 2-5 minutes of me leaving but now he has to move up to pre school class and the crying is even worse.
I am desperate to find out how to ease him and will this ever stop? I have a 31 year old and 27 year old and can not remember if they were this way. Anyone have suggestions?
The daycare is amazing so I know it’s not that. He has many friends as well. It’s just that drop off is so hard on us.

Comment: Hi Angie - this is really common, and in fact we have a few questions on it. I have closed as duplicate of the one that seems to be a duplicate.